# Parentheses and brackets with \Bigg comand

Tags: math-mode, equations, brackets

seems that the comands \Bigg  and \bigr don't give me a consitent size in the equation , here the code i used and the equations' output

```
\[C^{H}_{t}=\biggr\{\delta_{c}\bigl(\Lambda_{cy,t} Y^{C}_{t}\bigr)^{-\rho c}+(1-\delta_{c})\Bigg[\Bigg[\frac{(1-\delta_c)P_t/\Lambda_{cy,t}}{\delta_c P^M_t/(\Lambda_{cm,t}\Gamma_{cm}^{\dag})}\Bigg]^{\frac{1}{\rho c+1}}\Lambda_{cy,t} Y^{C}_{t}\Bigg]^{\rhoc}\biggr\}^{-1/\rho c}\]
```

output

[image]

the output should look like this :

[image]

Comment: Also, I kinda prefer the first one. There is no real reason for the outer bracers to be bigger than everything else. They are of a different kind an it is still clear to the reader how they match. Unless the square brackets mean something specifically I might even try making the inner most pair into () , and reducing the scaling of the []  a little bit.

Comment: the outermost braces are set with `\bigg` when you have something `\Bigg` inside of them, so of course the outer ones will be smaller.  also, i'm not sure why you have `\biggr\{` at the left; i would have expected `\biggl`.  and @daleif's comment about the relative sizing is relevant too; a trained editor wouldn't see the need for successively increasing the size when the expression isn't so complicated as to require it for clarity.

Answer (score 3):

The largest object in the formula is the central fraction, where the numerator and denominator have superscripts and subscripts, so the correct size seems to be `\bigg`.

You have also to distinguish between “left” and “right”, so use `\biggl` and `\biggr`. I also added `\,` before the closing brace, to give some more room for the exponent.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
C^{H}_{t}=\biggl\{
  \delta_{c}(\Lambda_{cy,t} Y^{C}_{t})^{-\rho c}+
  (1-\delta_{c})
  \biggl[
    \biggl(
      \frac{(1-\delta_c)P_t/\Lambda_{cy,t}}{\delta_c P^M_t/(\Lambda_{cm,t}\Gamma_{cm}^{\dag})}
    \biggr)^{\frac{1}{\rho c+1}}\Lambda_{cy,t} Y^{C}_{t}
  \biggr]^{\rho c}\,\biggr\}^{-1/\rho c}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]